# Keepass2, Debian Wheezy and Xfce 4.10 auto type problem

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

Keepass auto type stopped working. When I looked into keyboard settings and tried to change the shortcut, I somehow deleted the record, so I don't know what command was there before. So I tried `/usr/bin/cli /usr/lib/keepass2/KeePass.exe --auto-type` and it didn't work. However when Keepass is closed, the shortcut starts it, so I see the problem lies in the auto type part.